# Is it possible to turn off Ubuntu Server's GUI Screensaver

Tags: server, screensaver

I do not know how to properly explain this but i'm using Ubuntu Server to run RetroPie without overhead of Ubuntu Desktop. Basically, when Ubuntu Server is running in non-text mode, after around 10 minutes, the screen turns off. But by plugging in a mouse and moving it, the screen turns back on.

Is there any way to disable Ubuntu Server GUI Screensaver?

Edit: Turns out this non-text mode is aplications launching in a desktop like environment? The desktop like environment takes up the entire screen, it has a white background, and has mouse support. When i right click, it gives me a right-click menu. And when i press ALT + TAB, it allows me to switch between applications.

Comment: Ubuntu Server’s GUI? Did you install a desktop environment? I yes please [edit] and name it, the solution may be DE-specific.

Answer (score 0):

In the `/etc/default/grub` file you should have a line that has something along the lines of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`.

Edit that line to add `consoleblank=0` like so `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash consoleblank=0"`. You can use any regular text editor like `vim` or `nano`, or whatever you're comfortable with.

After that run `sudo update-grub` and then reboot.

This should solve the issue.

Comment: I think the file i need to edit is /etc/default/grub instead of /etc/grub/default

Comment: Yes, my apologies! I'll correct that in my answer. Thank you for that

Comment: If this solved your issue please mark it as resolved.